# Cannot connect to MySQL server via windows command line without error message

Tags: mysql

Here is my story. I installed MySQL server for windows and everything is fine. When I connect to MySQL via command line, I give a warning message:

> [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).

I fixed this issue by adding `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` in my .ini file. But I still cannot connect to MySQL server without any the error.

How do I fix it?

Comment: So what error message do you get now after fixing the first issue? Are we meant to _guess_?

Comment: I didn't get any message after I fixed first issue. Something like that
C:\mysqld -u root -p root_password
C:\

Comment: You are using the wrong command: `mysqld` is the _server_ executable. That is nothing you want to start from the command line. The server should be started as a service. What you want to use from the command line is the _client_ to connect to and interact with the server. The _client_ executable is called `mysql` (note the missing trailing `d`).

Comment: I follow your suggestion use mysql -u root -p root_password. MySQL server ask me type password again then I give an error message: ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'root_password'. If I leave the second password, I give an error message: ERROR 1045(28000): Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: NO).

Comment: Again a wrong command line: it should be `mysql -u root -p` only. You miss understood the example you copied. The password cannot be specified on the command line, you have to type it in interactively.